# how to Show my posts as well as followers posts MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a system like twitter where user can connect to each other & then they will be able to see each other post

here is the user table

```
+-----+------------+---------+
|  id |  name      |username |
+-----+------------+---------+
|   1 | Phillip    | user1   |
|   2 | Another    | user2   |
+-----+------------+---------+
```

connection table

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|      id | follower  |  following   |     status   |
+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------+             
|       1 |  user1    |  user2       |       0      |
|       2 |  user3    |  user1       |       1      |
+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

post table

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| post_id | content   |     title    |    username  |
+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------+             
|       1 | hello guyz|      eg1     |     user1    |
|       2 | example1  |      eg 2    |     user2    |
+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

query i tried

```
SELECT
post.* 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN connection ON (users.username = connection.follower
 OR users.username = connection.following)
INNER JOIN messages ON (
  users.username = post.username
  OR connection.following = post.username
)
WHERE users.username = 'user1'
GROUP BY post.id
LIMIT 0, 8
```

What could be wrong in this query as this query is also incomplete

To make you understand better->

Suppose my name is example & if i send request to example2 & he accept my request then `status will be set to 1` then  how can i see his posts on my timeline & how can he see my posts on his timeline

Comment: Better way would be to get all the user posts in one array and followers post in another array, later join them according to timestamp.

Comment: @Manikiran there may be thousand post and follower i can't get everyone into array thats totally wrong idea

Comment: No one gets all the data at once, like twitter, you only get posts which are posted after a certain period, later when you scroll, you are supposed to get older posts, this not only improves user load time, but also saves on complex queries.

Comment: One Question : `username` in `user` table is having unique key ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar yes username is unique like id

Comment: @PeterDarmis actually in my database there are thousand of users, it means if i follow you then we both will get connected & you can see my post and i can see your post, so if i have connected to 500 people then their updates must be shown on my timeline and my updates on their timeline. So i need a query in which if i followed you or you followed me we both will receive each other updates at our timeline like facebook does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query for the results you want is

```
SELECT * FROM `posts`
WHERE `username` = 'user1'
OR `username` IN (SELECT `follower` FROM `connection` WHERE `following`='user1' AND `status`=1)
```